# Terraform tries to destroy the imported AWS IAM user

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to import existing AWS IAM Users into terraform.
(Right now, there exist both terraform managed and unmanaged IAM Users.)

So I ran the following import for the unmanaged IAM user like `userA` as follow and it was successful and can see it in tfstate file.

```
terraform import aws_iam_user.create-users userA
```

Then I added `userA` in my terraform variable to run to see if terraform acknowledged, but it keeps trying to destroy the `userA` when running `terraform apply`.

How can I set Terraform managed `userA` without destroying?

My terraform scripts are like the following.

```
# main.tf

resource "aws_iam_user" "create-users" {
  for_each = var.users

  name = each.key

}
```

```
#user.auto.tfvars

users = {
  "testuser1" = {
        group = ["Admin"]
    },
  "testuser2" = {
        group = ["User"]
    },
   "userA" = {
        group = ["not managed"]
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I tried direct resource without for_each as follow, then terraform recognized.

```
#direct.tf

 resource "aws_iam_user" "existing" {
   name = "userA"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the keyname.

```
terraform import 'aws_iam_user.create-users["userA"]' userA
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the index_key was missing from tfstate file after edit the post and looking for proper import object.